# linguist-vendored and linguist-language not working in .gitattributes file

Tags: git, github, github-linguist

I am trying to use .gitattributes to specify the language of all `.h` files using `linguist-language=C` and make sure linguist doesn't include the SFML library in its tally using `linguist-vendored`. I counted up all the lines in my project (without the library of course) and the total amount of lines is 529. I counted all the lines in my `.c` and `Makefile` files (not the .h files) and they total to 31 lines.  I'm no mathematician, but the `.c` and `Makefile` files make up roughly 5% of my project, yet after committing the `.gitattributes` file specifying not to count the include files, it says that C++ makes up 99.7% of my project, when it should be roughly 95. I don't know what the problem is. Here is the `.gitattributes` file:

```
*.h linguist-language=C
./include/SFML/* linguist-vendored
```

and here is the link to the GitHub repo: https://github.com/reimeytal/pandemic-simulator
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linguist doesn't count the lines of code for each language, but the bytes.

---

**Source.** From [Linguist's README](https://github.com/github/linguist/#how-linguist-works):

> The result of this analysis is used to produce the language stats bar which displays the languages percentages for the files in the repository. The percentages are calculated based on the bytes of code for each language as reported by the List Languages API.